# How can I draw a filled rectangle in an applet with half opacity?

Tags: java, applet

How can I draw a filled rectangle in an applet with half opacity/transparency?

Comment: Do you mean, over the background of your applet? Or over the background of the web page itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What API are you using? 
If you use Graphics from Java2D, when you create Color objects, you can add transparency to them as an alpha between 0 and 1.

[Here's an old article on Java2D](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/swing2d/index.html) that has some examples

Comment: am using awt.Graphics.fillRect and awt.Graphics.setColor api calls.

Answer (score 8):

Yup.

```
void foo(Graphics g) {
  g.setColor(new Color(.3f, .4f, .5f, .6f);
  g.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Paul Murray's answer is exactly right. But to clarify, the mixing and matching of the 4 color switches is what makes different colors. Here are some of the basics to help you get started.

```
g.setColor(new Color(1f, 0f, 0f, 1f)); //RED
g.setColor(new Color(0f, 1f, 0f, 1f)); //GREEN
g.setColor(new Color(0f, 0f, 1f, 1f)); //BLUE
g.setColor(new Color(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f)); //BLACK
g.setColor(new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f)); //WHITE
```

and if you use decimal numbers you can make the color opaque. so:

```
g.setColor(new Color(.5f, 0f, 0f, .5f)); //RED
```

would be 50% opaque and red. then you can draw whatever with that opaque color. such as:

```
g.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 100);
```

as Paul stated